# Entity saving fails with not null constraint. Spring-boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have entities `User` and `School`.
There's a foreign key between them in MySQL database (one School has many Users).

In `User` I have:

```
@ManyToOne(optional = false, targetEntity = School.class, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "schoolId", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false)
private School school;
```

In `School` I have:

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, targetEntity = User.class)
@JoinColumn(name = "schoolId")
private List<User> users;
```

When I want to save `School` entity with `List<User>` inside it, I call

```
schoolRepository.save(school);
```

everything is fine, data is being saved to both `school` and `user` tables.

**BUT**

I need to add `not null constraint` to `user.school_id` column (I use `liquibase` for it), and when I do so and try to save `School` entity again, I receive:

`com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column 'school_id' cannot be null`.

How come? And how can it be fixed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is problem of bidirectional JPA relationships. **Updating one direction of relationship** (in your case `School.users`) **doesn't automatically update opposite direction of relationship** (in your case `User.school`). **You need to do it explicitly.**

In order to save them, you need to loop through list of users and set school field to your desired school. After that initialize list of users in school and save. Something like this:

```
users.stream().forEach(user -> user.setSchool(school));
school.setUsers(users);
schoolRepository.save(school);
```

BTW, I would suggest to google around bidirectional JPA relationships implications. After some research you will most probably end up with conclusion to avoid it as much as possible. Personally had to use only handful of bidirectional JPA relationships in my career. In vast majority of cases, uni-directional relationships are enough for your needs.

Comment: So if I need to add a **new** `school` with list of **new** `users`, I'll need to save `school` entity first, and then save the list of `users` with predefined `school_id`?

Comment: Not necessarily, your configuration is cascading users, so unsaved users would be saved with school, but such users needs to have not null school field to satisfy not null contraint.

Comment: I appreciate your help, but sorry, I'm still not getting it. Is there a way to save `school` entity (thereby receive the new `school.id` for it),  and put this `school.id` into each `user` entity in `user.school_id` in one `schoolRepository.save(school);` call? Maybe the relationship configuration between entities should be changed somehow?

Comment: Yes there is, just use Java. I updated my answer with the code